# meshgrid like function for a list of 3d arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to be able to compute a pairwise distance between a list (or array) of n-dimensional points. I would like to compute the distance matrix between a list of origin a destination.

I tried `np.meshgrid`, but it does not get me what I want. Probably I am using it wrong.

Image I have points `[x1,...,xn]` and `[y1,...,y_n]` and I want to construct the pair wise matrix `[[(x1,y1), .... , (x_n, y1)], ...., [(x_1, y_n), ...,(x_n, y_n)]`. It can also be two matrices containing xs and ys.

```py
n=2 %number of points
d=3 %dimesion of points

X = np.random.random((d, n))
Y = np.random.random((d, n))
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

xv.shape
>>(6,6)  %here I would like to obtain a 3x2x2 matrix
```

In math it is the distance matrix between a pair of tensors.
Probably the solution is some broadcasting magic...

Comment: In such complicated questions, you will do a big favor to yourself and the readers by including a small desired output (actual numbers and not variables x1, x2, x_n, y_n etc.).

Comment: you are right. I will do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
X1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
X2 = np.array([[7,8,9], [10,11,12]])

xv, yv = np.repeat(X1, 2).reshape(3,2,2), np.repeat(X2, 2).reshape(3,2,2).transpose((0,2,1))
```

That gives:

```
xv
>>array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [4, 4]],

       [[5, 5],
        [6, 6]]])
yv
>>array([[[ 7,  8],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[11, 12],
        [11, 12]]])
```

The desired matrix is obtained:

```
np.stack([xv, yv]).shape
>>
(2, 3, 2, 2)
```